# Average days between first and second purchase

Tags: mysql

can someone assist with the following. I need to figure out what the average day difference is between the first and second purchase of a customer:

I have the below: can someone assist with with my query please.

```
SELECT src.id, AVG(DATEDIFF(dest.purchasing, src.registrations)) AS avgdays FROM 
(SELECT accounts.id, accounts.`created_date` AS registrations FROM accounts
WHERE YEAR(accounts.`created_date`) =2018 AND MONTH(accounts.`created_date`) =4) src
INNER JOIN
(SELECT account_id, MIN(created_date) AS purchasing
FROM ordering 
WHERE STATUS = 'Fulfilled'
GROUP BY account_id
) dest
ON 
dest.account_id = src.id;
```

Comment: what's the problem ? Result you get and you want?

Comment: @DanielE. - this only gives me the first purchase, but i need to add in the second purchase made after the first purchase made and then get the AVG between the first and second purchase

Comment: No. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry - i know it's a simple query but can't seem to figure it out by just adding second purchase date.

Comment: You need to give us a sample of the data because like this it's difficult to know what to do.

Comment: @DanielE. - i just need to know how do you compare (from the query provided which is the first purchase date) how do you add when the user made a second purchase from their first purchase (did it take one day, two days, ect)

Answer (score -1):

The below query will give you the average difference between 2nd purchase if customer registration date is also his first order purchase date.

```
select account_id,customer_created, 
avg(DATEDIFF(order_created, customer_created))  from
(select a.account_id,b.created_at as order_created, a.created_at 
customer_created from
(select * from accounts where YEAR(created_at) =2018 AND 
MONTH(created_at) =4) a
INNER JOIN ordering b on a.account_id=b.account_id where 
b.status="Delivered" ) a 
where customer_created <> order_created  GROUP BY a.account_id ;
```